# how to take a generic JAXBElement as an input

Tags: java, generics, jaxb

I have a method

```
public Response xyz ( JAXBElement<T> request ) {
......
}
```

two different places it is getting called with different JAXBElement.
One with `xyz(JAXBElement<a>)` and other with `xyz(JAXBElement<B>)`

How can I make my method intake generic so that it works with both the methods?

Answer (score 2):

Please try:

```
xyz(JAXBElement<?> myElement);
```

Please see this [tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/extra/generics/wildcards.html) on generics:

> So what is the supertype of all kinds of collections? It's written
>   `Collection<?>` (pronounced "collection of unknown"), that is, a
>   collection whose element type matches anything. It's called a wildcard
>   type for obvious reasons. We can write:
>
> ```
> void printCollection(Collection<?> c) {
>     for (Object e : c) {
>         System.out.println(e);
>     }
> }
> ```
>
> and now, we can call it with any type of collection.